# Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Installation Stuck

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have tried installing different version of Microsoft SQL Server but for some reason the installation sticks at `RunningAction: InitializeMsiAction`.

[image: See Image of Installation]

Comment: @closevoter Questions about [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) are on-topic.

Comment: .NET Framework 3.5 enabled?

Comment: That step can take a long time running `ngen` to recompile .NET assemblies. If you open Windows Task Manager on the machine and go to the Details tab you should see a lot of ngen.exe processes coming and going. While that's happening the setup is proceeding, it's just busy. Because this is a SQL Server 2017 installation ngen should be working on .NET 4.0 assemblies.

Comment: @Daniel .NET Framework 4 is installed. Will It Work or do i need to install 3.5 specifically ?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Any Idea how much time will be required or what do i need to do ?

Comment: UPDATE : Turning Of The Firewall did the Job. It is installed now. Thank Your For Your Kind Responses